# Trouble compiling mongo-cxx-driver in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mongodb, boost, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm having some trouble when I try to compile the mongo-cxx-driver in Windows (Windows 7 and Visual Studio 17).

First I followed the instructions for Windows in http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#building-windows in order to build the mongo-c-driver with Visual Studio. The version I used was 1.13.1 and it seemed to work fine. I used the following commands:

```
cd mongo-c-driver-1.13.1
mkdir cmake-build
cd cmake-build

cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" \
  "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver" \
"-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver" \
..

msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
```

The problem comes when I try to build the mongo-cxx driver. I follow the steps in http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/ but there are some errors when I compile. The version is 3.4.0, and the version of boost is 1.59.0. I tried with the following commands:

```
mkdir mongo-cxx-build
cd mongo-cxx-build

cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-cxx-driver
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver
-DBOOST_ROOT=C:\local\boost_1_59_0 ..
```

[Output from the command above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpOVN.png)

But when I enter:

```
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

I get the following warnings/errors:
[Warnings from command above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ttf.png) 
[Errors from command above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0r9Z.png)

Some parts of the error output are in Spanish, but traduced to English basically say: The initialization of the copy list from boost::optional... can't use an explicit constructor.

Does anyone know why do I get this error?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: My bad. The problem was some misconfiguration with the installation of boost. https://theboostcpplibraries.com/introduction-installation